# align parent left programmatically android

Tags: android, layout

I have a recycler view and this recycler view inflates some messages. I am trying to change align those messages left programmatically, but it's not working. My layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_relative"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/row_background">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My code looks like this:

```
RelativeLayout cardViewRelative   = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.card_view_relative);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    messagesViewHolder.cardViewRelative.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

I have no idea what's wrong here.

Comment: You should put those "xmlns:android" only at the root of you layout. Also, where do you call the `setLayoutParams` method? Can you share your Adapter code?

Comment: If I were you, I bear in mind **android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"**... It doesn't let you align at the left

Comment: I found out my problem. I was trying to set the layout parameters on the relative layout, so it was not working. now I set it to the card view itself and it works. Thank you all